# Passing of modeladmin as a parameter in Custom List Filtering in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to do something if one modeladmin is passed and do another thing if another modeladmin is passed. But it seems that the modeladmin doesn't get passed as a parameter in list_filter while it does get passed in actions in django admin. why is this so?

```
from datetime import date

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class DecadeBornListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
    # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
    title = _('decade born')

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'decade'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        """
        Returns a list of tuples. The first element in each
        tuple is the coded value for the option that will
        appear in the URL query. The second element is the
        human-readable name for the option that will appear
        in the right sidebar.
        """
        return (
            ('80s', _('in the eighties')),
            ('90s', _('in the nineties')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Returns the filtered queryset based on the value
        provided in the query string and retrievable via
        `self.value()`.
        """
        # Compare the requested value (either '80s' or '90s')
        # to decide how to filter the queryset.
        if self.value() == '80s':
            return queryset.filter(birthday__gte=date(1980, 1, 1),
                                    birthday__lte=date(1989, 12, 31))
        if self.value() == '90s':
            return queryset.filter(birthday__gte=date(1990, 1, 1),
                                    birthday__lte=date(1999, 12, 31))
```

For example, in the example above, i would like to do something different if it is a student which is to check the birthday is between 90's or 2000's. But it is the parent, i would like to check if the birthday is between 70's or 80's? Just assume that different modeladmin will be passed. How do i include the modeladmin as parameter to do these changes?  Need some guidance on this...

Comment: Do you mean that 0) model_admin is passed to lookups() method that's OK but 1) model_admin is not passed to queryset() method so that's a problem for you ?

Comment: ya... i passed model_admin in a parameter into queryset like this: queryset(self, request, queryset, model_admin) but it gives me this error: queryset() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given).

Comment: Maybe because model_admin is not passed to the queryset() method.

Comment: any idea how to involve model_admin? sorry to trouble you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set self.model_admin:

```
class DecadeBornListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    #[...]

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        self.model_admin = model_admin
        # ...

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        # here you can use self.model_admin
```

Or, use inheritance:

```
class BaseDecadeBornListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    # [...]


class DecadeBornListFilter1(BaseDecadeBornListFilter):
    # [...]


class DecadeBornListFilter2(BaseDecadeBornListFilter):
    # [...]


class StudentModelAdmin1(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (DecadeBornListFilter1,)


class StudentModelAdmin2(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (DecadeBornListFilter2,)
```

Comment: i tried if isinstance(modeladmin, Student). It doesn't work. Why is it wrong? do you know...

Comment: Maybe because model_admin would be an instance of StudentAdmin. Did you try my code ? if model_admin.model == Student ? I tested it, it works B)

Comment: both my models are from Student,that's why. need something to do with modeladmin.. thats why...

Comment: i actually tried if isinstance(modeladmin, StudentAdmin). not isinstance(modeladmin, Student)

Comment: Maybe because you use "modeladmin" instead of "model_admin" ? Using "model_admin" see [this paste](http://dpaste.com/792019/). One question: what's wrong with the code in my answer ?

Comment: as i said,both my models are from Student.... it only varies in the model_admin...

Comment: I see, you have 2 admin sites then. You could use a variant of the second code example I posted.

Comment: i also tried isinstance(model_admin, StudentAdmin) and i get error: global name 'model_admin' is not defined...